# Alternating geometric series, not sure what i am looking at

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, geometric-series

I have written out a series describing a model system but i cannot find if there is a historical representation of the like series:

$$N_s= N\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}P^i$$

It appears to be an alternating geometric series, similar to the Mercator series.

Comment: Write the term as $-1(-P)^i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}P^i=-\sum_{i=1}^n(-P)^i=-\left(\frac{1-(-P)^{n+1}}{1-(-P)}-1\right)=\frac{P+(-P)^{n+1}}{1+P}$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) for details.

Then

$$N_s=N\frac{P+(-P)^{n+1}}{1+P}$$

Comment: denominator (-1) multiplier was left out

Comment: Fixed. What I originally had would have been true if the sum had started at $i=0$.